# How to make a 2D string array that follows rules to create different paths depending on inputs in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an assignment that I am not sure how to go about solving in java. The assignment calls for a program that takes 5 lines of input, each of 5 lower case letters without spaces in between. Each of these lines would be a row in the array. One of the letters must be a, a couple will be letters between b and y, and the rest are z which is considered the "empty" cells. The program is meant to get rid of all the z letters, replacing them with the rest of the letters in the alphabet that have not been used yet, following a path starting from a in which the following letter must be adjacent. So a has to be next to b which has to be next to c. This is without changing the already existing non z letters from the input. For example:

```
input        output

zzzzm        ijklm
zzzzz        hgpon
zfzzz  --->  efqrs
zzzaz        dcbat
zzzzu        yxwvu
```

Another example of potential input/output:

[image: Another example of potential input/output]

As can be seen the a was followed by a b on the right and so on it wrapped around the array, weaving a path through the preexisting letters. I am unsure as to how to go about this at all honestly. How do you use the preexisting letters to figure out the proper path for the letters to go through?

All I have so far is:

```
public class AtoY {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int row =-1; int col =-1;
    String[][] arr = new String[5][5];
    String L1 = "zzzzm";
    String L2 = "zzzzz";
    String L3 = "zfzzz";
    String L4 = "zzzaz";
    String L5 = "zzzzu";
    for (int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
            if (x==0){
                arr[x][y]=L1.substring(y, y+1);
                if(arr[x][y]=="a"){
                    row=x;
                    col=y;
                }
                //System.out.println(L1.substring(y, y+1));
            }
            if (x==1){
                arr[x][y]=L2.substring(y, y+1);
                if(arr[x][y]=="a"){
                    row=x;
                    col=y;
                }
                //System.out.println(L2.substring(y, y+1));
            }if (x==2){
                arr[x][y]=L3.substring(y, y+1);
                if(arr[x][y]=="a"){
                    row=x;
                    col=y;
                }
                //System.out.println(L3.substring(y, y+1));
            }if (x==3){
                arr[x][y]=L4.substring(y, y+1);
                if(arr[x][y]=="a"){
                    row=x;
                    col=y;
                }
                //System.out.println(L4.substring(y, y+1));
                //System.out.println(arr[x][y]);
            }if (x==4){
                arr[x][y]=L5.substring(y, y+1);
                if(arr[x][y]=="a"){
                    row=x;
                    col=y;
                }
                //System.out.println(L5.substring(y, y+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bunch of if statements and the written inputs is there for now just for testing purposes, i will put in a scanner to take whatever lines eventually, and fix it so there is only 1 if statement to look for a. The reason i put that up there is mainly because i am also having another issue that I am unsure about in regards to finding a. when it gets to `x=3`, or the 4th row, and `y=3`, the 4th column, the if statement of `if arr[3][3] == "a"` should be true and row and col should change their values, but they don't. Is the if statement being treated as if it were false? and if so why?

Sorry if this is all really basic, I couldn't find anything about this problem or one similar to it (maybe I just didn't know how to word it properly) so I decided to just ask. Thank you for taking the time to read this and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Some (important) side notes: use `arr[x][y].equals("a")` and not `==a` . Change 4 (out of 5) `if` statement to `else if` because you only check for one `x` value each loop.  Also there is no need to repeat code: put the repeating code block in a method.  Why assign values to `row` and `col` which are never used ?  The **logic** of the replacement is not quiet clear to me: I assume that each line in dependent on all other lines, Is that correct ?. The vertical and horizontal dependency is also not clear to  me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have heard your tutor muttering the words "backtracking" and "recursion". I'm going to assume that those
are the tools they want you to exercise.

You should set up the input in a two dimensional `char` array. This will allow you to address each character in the
array with your *x* and *y* coordinates without having to do messy `substring` manipulation. As part of the setup you
should validate the input (check that the chars are legal, check for duplicate chars, check that each row has five
chars, check that there are five rows.). Then find the coordinates of **a**.

You'll also need a support function to check whether a character placement is legal. It needs to check that the *x* and
*y* coordinates it's passed are within the bounds of the array, and that the character at the coordinates is **z** or
matches the candidate character.

Once you've done that pass the initial state (the array, the start char, and the coordinates of the start char) to your
recursive function.

Your recursive function only needs to place one character (the one following what it gets passed). If it succeeds in
placing the character it should *call itself* to place the next character. If it can't place the character it should
return a flag to indicate failure. If it succeeds in placing the character **y** it should return a flag to indicate
that the solution has been found.

The function has to loop through each possible placement choice it has (the four adjacent locations to its input
position). For each legal placement it finds it needs to update the array and call itself, passing the new state. If
the recursive call returns "false" it needs to rollback the change and try the next placement (the "backtracking" bit).

In code:

```
/**
 * Enum to encapsulate the four possible directions to step in.
 */
enum Direction {
    N(1, 0), S(-1, 0), E(0, 1), W(0, -1);

    int dx;
    int dy;

    Direction(int dx, int dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }
}

/**
 * Place a character.
 * 
 * @param state the current state of the puzzle
 * @param currentChar the last character placed
 * @param x the x coordinate of the last character placed
 * @param y the y coordinate of the last character placed
 *          
 * @return true if the solution was found
 */
public static boolean step(char[][] state, char currentChar, int x, int y) {
    // Increment the character we're placing.
    currentChar++;

    // Try a step in each direction.
    for (Direction direction: Direction.values()) {
        // The coordinates to place the character.
        int nx = x + direction.dx;
        int ny = y + direction.dy;

        // Is the placement legal?
        if (checkPlacement(state, nx, ny, currentChar)) {
            // Remember the old character in case we need to backtrack.
            char oldChar = state[nx][ny];
            // Record the step.
            state[nx][ny] = currentChar;

            // Stop if we're done, or recurse to perform the next step.
            if (currentChar == 'y' || step(state, currentChar, nx, ny))
                return true;

            // Didn't find the solution on this branch.
            // Backtrack and continue to try the next direction.
            state[nx][ny] = oldChar;
        }
    }

    // Tried all directions without success.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd shove all your chars into a 2D array :

```
arr[0]=L1.toCharArray();
arr[1]=L2.toCharArray();
arr[2]=L3.toCharArray();
arr[3]=L4.toCharArray();
arr[4]=L5.toCharArray();
```

Then I'd write a method that finds a given letter in the arrays, such as:

```
int[] findLetterCoordinate (char c)
```

Finally, I'd look for the "a", find the first free space near it, put a "b", and recursively try. When you're stuck, delete the previous letter and look for another space.

Those are ideas, you're the one supposed to flesh it out.